# What does PS stand for in PS/2?

Tags: terminology

[PS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector)

Anyone knows?

Comment: Play Station :P

Comment: I seem to remember the expression "PS/2 little, OS/2 late"...

Comment: What's OS/2 for?

Comment: Piece of S... . =D | @wamp - "The name stands for "Operating System/2," because it was introduced as part of the same generation change release as IBM's" from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2

Answer (score 20):

[IBM Personal System 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_System/2).

> The Personal System/2 or PS/2 was
>   IBM's third generation of personal
>   computers. The PS/2 line, released to
>   the public in 1987, was created by IBM
>   in an attempt to recapture control of
>   the PC market by introducing an
>   advanced proprietary architecture.

[...]

> PS/2 systems introduced a new
>   specification for the keyboard and
>   mouse interfaces, which are still in
>   use today and are thus called "PS/2"
>   interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Petrotta mentioned it is the Personal System/2 from IBM which defined the new "Standard" as a time when proprietary connections were the standard.

http://computer-engineering.org/ps2protocol/

> IBM introduced a new keyboard with each of its major desktop computer
>   models.  The original IBM PC, and later the IBM XT, used what we call
>   the "XT keyboard."  These are obsolete and differ significantly from
>   modern keyboards; the XT keyboard is not covered in this article. 
>   *Next came the IBM AT system and later the IBM PS/2.  They introduced the keyboards we use today, and are the topic of this article.  AT
>   keyboards and PS/2 keyboards were very similar devices, but the PS/2
>   device used a smaller connector and supported a few additional
>   features*.  Nonetheless, it remained backward compatible with AT
>   systems and few of the additional features ever caught on (since
>   software also wanted to remain backward compatible.)  Below is a
>   summary of IBM's three major keyboards.